# Testing method inside method Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

Can I test a method inside a method in Python?

**search.py**

```
   def SearchWeb(query=None):
        """Search via API"""
        search = cool_api.api_request(query)
        def _HandleResponse(search):
            if search:
              return search['result']
        return _HandleResponse(search)
```

I want to create a test method for `_HandleResponse` using unittest

**search_test.py**

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        response = {}
        response['result'] = 'yes'
        self.assertEqual(search._HandleResponse(response), 'yes')
```

But `_HandleResponse` is not accessible. I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_HandleResponse'
```

I can move `_HandleResponse` outside `SearchWeb` method and that works, but wondering if this is possible?

Comment: It's not possible, the method is actually created every time the function is called. This means you have no static reference to it and you can't write a test. You have to test it through the `SearchWeb` function.

Comment: Can you change this to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it's not possible.

The nested method is actually created every time the function is called. This means you have no static reference to it and you can't write a test to a function that doesn't exist. You have to test it through the `SearchWeb` function.

**Side note**: Technically there are probably (complex) things you can do but none that I can think of are worth mentioning.